# count sum of values of selected radio buttons which have particular data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have radio buttons and they have different data-id and a value assigned to each radio button. i want to count sum of values of selected radio buttons where data-id=OriginalityOfIdeas. I want to do it with jquery. I am trying to do but not able to achieve my goal.

I want to count between particular div or class.

```
<div class="multisteps-form__content">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb1" name="1" value="1" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
          <label for="Q_1_rb1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">The event should be organized in the same way as every year. </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb2" name="1" value="3" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
          <label for="Q_1_rb2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could introduce some Virtual Reality games. </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb3" name="1" value="2" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
          <label for="Q_1_rb3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could make it different and more engaging, but need to think about how. </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb4" name="1" value="4" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
          <label for="Q_1_rb4" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could invite some guest artists to perform during the day of the event.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb5" name="1" value="5" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
          <label for="Q_1_rb5" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could invite ideas from students to showcase their unique talent not known to others.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="multisteps-form__content">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb1" name="2" value="2" data-id="Curiosity">
          <label for="Q_2_rb1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">Gather some information about them </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb2" name="2" value="4" data-id="Curiosity">
          <label for="Q_2_rb2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">Know in detail about the diverse cultures </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb3" name="2" value="3" data-id="Curiosity">
          <label for="Q_2_rb3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">Gather information from my team members</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb4" name="2" value="5" data-id="Curiosity">
          <label for="Q_2_rb4" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">Gather information from various sources </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb5" name="2" value="1" data-id="Curiosity">
          <label for="Q_2_rb5" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">Does not matter to me </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                var dataID = "OriginalityOfIdeas";
                var checked = $("input[type='radio'][data-id='" + dataID + "']:checked");
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
                    sum += parseInt(checked.eq(i).attr("value"), 10);
                }
```

Comment: I want sum to value column of selected radio buttons which have data-id=OriginalityOfIdeas

Answer (score 0):

You can find the checked radio items by running a filter function against the list of found radio buttons (criterion:checked) within a certain group (according to the data test id).

However, you will always get either 1 radio button selected or 0 because that's how radio's work, it's not like a checkbox, selecting another one will cause the previous one to deselect.

the below code should get you going:

```js
function getSelectedRadioButtonAmount(dataId) {
  const arr = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-id=${dataId}]`);
  return Array.from(arr).filter(x => x.checked).length
}


document.getElementById('find-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const amount = getSelectedRadioButtonAmount('OriginalityOfIdeas');
  console.log('number of selected radios', amount)

})
```

```html
<div class="multisteps-form__content">
        <button id="find-button">
          Find checked radios
        </button>
        
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 align-items-center">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb1" name="1" value="1" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
                <label for="Q_1_rb1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">The event should be organized in the same way as every year. </label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb2" name="1" value="3" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
                <label for="Q_1_rb2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could introduce some Virtual Reality games. </label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb3" name="1" value="2" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
                <label for="Q_1_rb3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could make it different and more engaging, but need to think about how. </label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb4" name="1" value="4" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
                <label for="Q_1_rb4" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could invite some guest artists to perform during the day of the event.</label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb5" name="1" value="5" data-id="OriginalityOfIdeas">
                <label for="Q_1_rb5" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">We could invite ideas from students to showcase their unique talent not known to others.</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I want sum to value column of selected radio buttons which have data-id=OriginalityOfIdeas

Comment: @harry your sum will be always one for that group so you don;t need to sum it, you cannot have more than one radio button checked

Comment: i want to sum value of radio buttons... not radio buttons count.. your code is counting..